# PHP/MySQL - Ordering rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a row to return all of the users for a particular project, which isn't a problem. However, how would I order it so that the first result is always the logged in user.

I see two solutions, both of which I've tried with no success:

1. Printing the user's name then using an if statement to only print the rest of the row if they are different from the user's name.

   ```
   print user's name;
   if (username !== user's name) {
       print this name;
   }
   ```
2. Printing them all in a row but ordering it somehow so that the current user is at the top.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm trying it now with the following code:

```
$query7 = mysql_query("SELECT users_ID FROM projects_users WHERE projects_id = '$id' AND WHERE users_id <>'$q6[0]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

But I get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE users_id <>'1'' at line 1
```

I've tried != and NOT instead of <> but I can't see what's going wrong!

Never mind, fixed it. For future reference, don't sure WHERE twice ;)

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Please show your query code and your output code.

Comment: added some info in my answerù

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first solution is perfect.

If you want to use your second solution you should build your SQL query like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :currentUserID) UNION (SELECT * FROM user)
```

And you are good

Comment: and this could be a comment @yes123 instead of an answer.

Comment: +1 for speed :) Don't forget to exclude from the last query the user found in the first query, so you don't get it twice.

Comment: @coding: he asked how to do the second solution. Isn't that an answer?

Comment: @radu: I know it's pretty bad when you waste time when already one posted an answer. Stackoverflow should implement some more advanced LIVE notification when you are writing an answer

Comment: @radu: regarding the exclude. You don't need that beacuse `UNION` isn't `UNION ALL` :)

Comment: @yes123, how about `select * from user order by (user = :cuid) DESC` :-) Then you'll only have to go though the data once.

Comment: @johan: is that portable? I don't think.. UNION i believe is the most portable

Comment: @yes123, I do believe all SQL-dialects have `order by` :-) and boolean true == 1 and boolean false ==0 always.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with a simple mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY FIELD(username, 'username');
```

To learn more:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: @Sebastian I saw that you found a solution to your question, but just wanted to make sure you saw this. It should solve your problem with just a single query without having to do any more work. Here's a tutorial on ordering by specific field values with MySQL: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use php than, You can try something like this

```
$currentuser = "";

$otherusers = "";

if(username == user's name)
{

$currentuser = username;

}
else
{
 $otherusers .= username;

}

echo $currentuser;
echo $otherusers;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM USERS
 ORDER BY  (CASE user_id WHEN :currentUserID THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```